# Sub-linear functional $f$ satisfies $f(0)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $f$ be a sub-linear functional  on a real vector space $X$ satisfying $f(x)+f(y)\ge f(x+y);f(\alpha x)=\alpha f(x);\alpha>0$

> Show that it satisfies $f(0)=0 $

**Thoughts:**

Now $f(x+y)\leq f(x)+f(y)\implies f(0+0)\le f(0)+f(0)=2f(0)\implies f(0)\ge 0$

How to show that $f(0)\le 0$? Any help

Comment: Sublinearity is irrelevant. Try seeing what happens for $\alpha = 2$.

Comment: I can't see why is sublinearity irrelevant ?@T.Bongers

Comment: Perhaps irrelevant is too strong. It's completely unnecessary since you have $f(\alpha x) = \alpha f(x)$.

Comment: but here $\alpha>0$

Comment: Yes, so take $\alpha = 2$. That's greater than zero.

Comment: $f(2x)=2f(x);f(2x)\le f(x)+f(x)$ What next

Comment: What is $f(2 \cdot 0)$?

Comment: Oh right $f(0)=2f(0)\implies f(0)=0$ is it?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thank you very much @T.Bongers

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewrite your definition. Your definition is a definition of a superlinear functional.

What about 
$0=\frac{1}{3}0 + \frac{1}{3}0$, and by sublinearity you have
$$f(0)\leq \frac{1}{3}f(0)+\frac{1}{3}f(0)=\frac{2}{3}f(0).$$
This implies $\frac{1}{3}f(0)\leq 0$. Multiplying by $3$ you get $f(0)\leq 0.$

Comment: that's the given def. in Kreyszig